# systemd problem upgrading from impish to jelly fish (WSL2)

Tags: systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to upgrade my WSL2 distro from Impish to Jammy Jellyfish and running into problems with what I assume is systemd. I just installed the new wsl version from the Windows store to enable systemd support and not sure if this is related. Not sure where to go from here.

running `sudo do-release-upgrade` results in:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
```

Running 'sudo apt upgrade' results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 248.3-1ubuntu8.6) but 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 is installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 248.3-1ubuntu8.6) but 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 is installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 248.3-1ubuntu8.2) but 248.3-1ubuntu8.6 is installed
 systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 248.3-1ubuntu8.6) but 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 is installed
 systemd-timesyncd : Depends: systemd (= 248.3-1ubuntu8.6) but 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 is installed
 udev : Breaks: systemd (< 248.3-1ubuntu8.6) but 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  systemd
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container
The following packages will be upgraded:
  systemd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 126 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4405 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4096 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 45441 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_248.3-1ubuntu8.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (248.3-1ubuntu8.6) over (248.3-1ubuntu8.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_248.3-1ubuntu8.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_248.3-1ubuntu8.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out between a few different but semi-related issues. Simply, I think it was just needing to reinstall systemd. The following worked for me:

```bash
# Reverting to old sources:
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# Reinstall systemd:
sudo apt install --reinstall systemd

#Update distro:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

# Upgrade to new version:
sudo do-release-upgrade
```